# Formatting text within UILabel differently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I'd like different words in a UILabel to be different colors. Does this mean each word will need to be a different UILabel? I'm guessing yes, though sure would be nice to just put color codes in the label somehow, you know? I guess I'm a bit spoiled by text markup in HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no proper `UIRichTextView` in iOS. It's high on my wish-list for iOS 6 (and there's some reason to believe we may get it then due to the release of Pages).

Your options are to use multiple `UILabel` views, [NSString UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html), Core Text, `UIWebView`, or one of a few third-party frameworks such as:

- NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML
- CoreTextWrapper
- OHAttributedLabel
- OmniUI

All of the current solutions have different problems. The most common problem is that it's hard to get select and copy functionality to work with rich text unless you use a web view. Web views are incredibly annoying because they're asynchronous and you have to do a lot of your interactions in JavaScript.

I wish there were a better answer.

(Obligatory shilling: This topic is covered in depth in Chapter 18 of [iOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119961327).)

Answer (score 2):

UILabel doesn't support segmented formatting (the entire thing can only have one format).

Have a look at [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel), which does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware you'd need to have separate labels for each different coloured word. Depending what you're trying to do you may be able to make use of `myLabel.textColor` to change the colour of the periodically or on events etc.