# Change font of selected text in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, fonts, uitextview

Can anybody suggest me how to change the font of the selected text in UITextView.I cannot use UIWebView since i have to edit the text. I have seen the Pages app.How it is possible in that app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3841108/uitextfield-make-text-bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Formatting text within UILabel differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613723/formatting-text-within-uilabel-differently).

Since you need editing, you should also look at JavaScript-based editors such as [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/). I also highly recommend the [WWDC 2011 video](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/) for Session 511: "Rich Text Editing in Safari on iOS."

Answer (score 1):

My article on rich text UILabels may help... details and code can be found [here!](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/06/interactive-rich-text-uilabel/)

We're also about to finish a follow-up article which is basically an HTML text renderer with styles, bullets etc, this can render to a context so can render to a UIView or a PDF context for example. If you're not particularly in a hurry I can drop you a line when it is complete....